# MSI creation with Visual Studio 2008 - how to create a subdirectory?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create an MSI installer.  I currently have all the files installed in the main directory.  Is there a way to select some files to go in a subdirectory?
I can find an option in Visual Studio to do that.
Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have a project that is a "Setup Project".

Right click the project name from the solution explorer and choose view then File System.

On the left side of the screen right click the Application Folder and choose "Add Folder"

Give your folder a name.

Right click that folder and choose Add File.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to find. Thanks for your help.
Tony